# Wrapping static library in Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a fat static library with 2 architecture slices (armv7, arm64).
I'm trying to make it work with swift and wrap it into Cocoa Touch Framework.

What I do:

1. Create Cocoa Touch Framework project
2. Drag .a static library with headers
3. Set `OTHER_LDFLAGS` to `-all_load`
4. Set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO`
5. Set `VALID_ARCHS` and `ARCHS` to `armv7` and `arm64`
6. Build with Release build configuration
7. Grab .framework file from DerivedData/../../Products/

When I put this .framework into my swift project, add to Embedded Binaries section in my targets general settings, import framework and use one of its classes, I'm getting `undefined symbols for architecture arm64` or `undefined symbols for architecture armv7`.

EDIT:
Not sure if it helps but I've noticed that size of static library is about 34MB but size of generated .framework is about 12MB.

EDIT 2:
I ran `nm -arch arm64 -g myLibraryName` on both static library and generated dynamic library. The dynamic library doesn't contain all symbols that static library has. Seems like XCode build process strips lots of them.

Comment: To clarify do you want to distribute the library inside your framework? Do you just want to be able to use library inside your framework or are you also trying to expose the library to apps that embed your framework?  Finally is there a `.dylib` version available of the static library?

Comment: @tdbit I'm trying to wrap static library to Cocoa Touch Framework because I want to use swift. As you know, swift doesn't support static libraries. No, `.dylib` is not available.

Comment: Make sure you are creating library proper way. check below links for proper way to create dynamic framework.

> https://www.insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/ 
> https://possiblemobile.com/2016/08/ios-frameworks-part-2-build-and-ship/

Comment: Im afraid there is not enough info to find the source of problem yet. Have you added your lib to linked libraries? What target architectures selected in build settings? Have you build for simulator target or for a device? What symbols are undefined as there is a chance what some dylib is used in yor library?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do this? I'm facing the same issue…

Answer (score 3):

I think you have also forgotten to add :

**Project**->**Target**->**Build Phases**->**Link Binary With Libraries**:
add + the: `libz.dylib` or `libz.tbd`
(Since Xcode 7 the `*.dylib` files are `now *.tbd` files)

Be sure to also clean the folder: `/User/yourname/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData`

P.S: If you want you should also be able to add the `libz.tbd` from *"Other Linker Flags"* in the **Build Settings** by adding the argument -lz.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I think the issue is that linker doesnt add all symbols to generated dynamic lib. I just checked with `nm` command. My settings are: `Strip Debug Symbols Druing Copy` - `No`, `Strip Linked Product` - `No`, `Strip Style` - `Debugging Symbols`, `Dead code stripping` - `Yes`. I tried to set `Dead code stripping` to `No` but framework doesnt compile.

Comment: Btw, static library is older webrtc build with some custom changes in c++ code if that helps. However, this static lib works fine in old Obj-C projects.

Comment: Very strange, maybe you just know it,  take a look to the official webrtc/ios  [link](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) if it could be useful, especially the settings part..

Comment: Yup, but why xcode strips these symbols which exists in static library? I believe it has nothing to do with webrtc build process

Comment: Have you read the latest line of that link: your issue seems a problem related to list of architectures in the build script used to made your framework.Anyway following the instructions you can **split the binary and recreate it without x86-64**, there is also a [link](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/) to do it. You can make a try and see if this is your problem..

Comment: I think it's not a source of the problem. Your link refers to stripping out simulator architectures for AppStore builds.

Comment: @tailec so in the end were you able to figure it out? Because you awarded the bounty but your comments suggests it didn't work for you. What I did to fix it was create a dummy public class in my framework where I imported a class from the static libraries. This seems to prevent the symbol stripping, but it's not the most elegant solution.