# Can't wrap static library in Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I tried the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340662/wrapping-static-library-in-cocoa-touch-framework) link. I added all linked libraries which should also include a library called `myLib.a`, but I got an `undefined symbols for architecture arm64` error.

Furthermore, when I used the command `nm -arch arm64 -g myLibraryName`, I found out that the symbols in `myLib.a` were missing.

Comment: So you are trying to wrap one of your static lib in Dynamic framework ?

Comment: @technerd Exactly,  a third party static library which I want to use in Swift project.

Comment: So you are using Static lib directly in your application or embedding it in dynamic framework and then using that dynamic framework ?

Comment: @technerd I'm going to embed it in dynamic framework because I'm using private podspecs.

Comment: I also tried same thing months ago but embedding Static library in dynamic framework not worked so far.